# How should non-member functions be declared and defined in the .h file and cpp file?

Tags: c++

I don't really understand the concept of "non member function" in C++. How should non-member functions be declared and defined in the .h file and cpp file. and how to call the non member function in main.cpp since the non member function does not declared inside a class?

Comment: Someone here was a Java programmer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

non-member function or "free function" is a function that lives outside of a class.
To create a function like that you can just declare it outside of the class.

.h

```
Class C
{
     int func1(){}; //member function declared and defined in header
     int func2();   //member function declared in header
     ...
}

int func(){}; //free-function declared and defined in header file
int func2();  //free-function declared in header file
```

.cpp

```
int C::func2(){} //definition of member function
int func2(){}     //definition of free-function
int func3(){}     //free-function that is declared and defined in the source file. can only be used within this file
```

You can see that I used the same function names for both the member function and the free-functions, that is fine because they live in a different namespace.

Comment: "**in a different namespace**" did you mean scope? or is it the same.

Comment: @skrrt - People refer to it informally as either, since the definition of a class implicitly creates a namespace with the same name as that class.   Another term, which is arguably (you'll find lots of opinions if you search for a discussion) more technically correct than either, is "context".

Comment: I think it's a matter of semantics. The fact is that classes have their own namespaces.